# Embulk: Cannot insert data from MySQL to BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to put data from mysql to bigquery using embulk. Most of the tasks is succeeded, successfully put mysql data to bigquery. But some tasks are failed.

I got the error below, but couldn't get what this error means and how to solve this.

The main error message is this.

```
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Error) failed during waiting a Load job, get_job(boxil-186303, embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c), errors:[{:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"E    rror while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3452; errors: 1."}, {:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 9, but line st    arting at position:40711531 contains only 9 columns."}]
```

Full message is this.

```
2017-12-21 16:44:04.872 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Using local thread executor with max_threads=4 / output tasks 2 = input tasks 1 * 2
2017-12-21 16:44:04.942 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): embulk-output-bigquery: Get dataset... boxil-186303:boxil_production
2017-12-21 16:44:06.983 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): embulk-output-bigquery: Create table... boxil-186303:boxil_production.LOAD_TEMP_517f0049_a38d_47b4_8b58_cff20235bcef_visits_20161101
2017-12-21 16:44:07.489 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): {done:  0 / 1, running: 0}
2017-12-21 16:44:07.632 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetch size is 10000. Using server-side prepared statement.
2017-12-21 16:44:07.667 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): SQL: SELECT
  id,
  visit_token,
  visitor_token,
  ip,
  user_agent,
  referrer,
  landing_page,
  referring_domain,
  search_keyword,
  browser,
  os,
  device_type,
  user_id,
  started_at
FROM visits
WHERE started_at BETWEEN "2016-11-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-11-31 23:59:59";

2017-12-21 16:46:02.990 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): > 115.32 seconds
2017-12-21 16:46:03.129 +0900 [INFO] (embulk-output-executor-0): embulk-output-bigquery: create tmp.30909.2000.csv.gz
2017-12-21 16:46:03.156 +0900 [INFO] (embulk-output-executor-1): embulk-output-bigquery: create tmp.30909.2002.csv.gz
2017-12-21 16:46:04.150 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 500 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:04.853 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 1,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:05.761 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 2,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:06.804 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 4,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:08.517 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 8,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:11.501 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 16,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:14.267 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 32,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:19.126 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 64,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:28.404 +0900 [INFO] (0019:task-0000): Fetched 128,000 rows.
2017-12-21 16:46:45.547 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): {done:  1 / 1, running: 0}
2017-12-21 16:46:45.832 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job starting... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] tmp.30909.2002.csv.gz => boxil-186303:boxil_production.LOAD_TEMP_517f0049_a38d_47b4_8b58_cff20235bcef_visits_20161101
2017-12-21 16:46:45.851 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job starting... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] tmp.30909.2000.csv.gz => boxil-186303:boxil_production.LOAD_TEMP_517f0049_a38d_47b4_8b58_cff20235bcef_visits_20161101
2017-12-21 16:47:20.535 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] elapsed_time:6.2e-05sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:23.457 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] elapsed_time:4.7e-05sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:30.939 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] elapsed_time:10.406206sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:33.839 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] elapsed_time:10.381938sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:41.235 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] elapsed_time:20.702173sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:44.130 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] elapsed_time:20.672874999999998sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:51.504 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] elapsed_time:30.971776000000002sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:47:54.395 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] elapsed_time:30.937468000000003sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:48:01.809 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] elapsed_time:41.276272sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:48:04.678 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] elapsed_time:41.220437sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:48:12.104 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-2: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job checking... job_id:[embulk_load_job_b1bf6cf050d1cb16ca3a782cc37e17a6] elapsed_time:51.571353sec status:[RUNNING]
2017-12-21 16:48:14.944 +0900 [INFO] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: Load job completed... job_id:[embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c] elapsed_time:51.486924sec status:[DONE]
2017-12-21 16:48:14.945 +0900 [ERROR] (Ruby-0-Thread-1: /etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:144): embulk-output-bigquery: failed during waiting a Load job, get_job(boxil-186303, embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c), errors:[{:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3452; errors: 1."}, {:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 9, but line starting at position:40711531 contains only 9 columns."}]
2017-12-21 16:48:14.948 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): embulk-output-bigquery: Delete table... boxil-186303:boxil_production.LOAD_TEMP_517f0049_a38d_47b4_8b58_cff20235bcef_visits_20161101
2017-12-21 16:48:15.796 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): embulk-output-bigquery: delete tmp.30909.2000.csv.gz
2017-12-21 16:48:15.804 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): embulk-output-bigquery: delete tmp.30909.2002.csv.gz
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Error) failed during waiting a Load job, get_job(boxil-186303, embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c), errors:[{:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3452; errors: 1."}, {:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 9, but line starting at position:40711531 contains only 9 columns."}]
  at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(BulkLoader.java:375)
  at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:607)
  at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:35)
  at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:391)
  at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:387)
  at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:25)
  at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:387)
  at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:180)
  at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.runInternal(EmbulkRunner.java:337)
  at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.run(EmbulkRunner.java:174)
  at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.runSubcommand(EmbulkRun.java:467)
  at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.run(EmbulkRun.java:99)
  at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Error) failed during waiting a Load job, get_job(boxil-186303, embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c), errors:[{:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3452; errors: 1."}, {:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 9, but line starting at position:40711531 contains only 9 columns."}]
  at RUBY.wait_load(/etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:324)
  at RUBY.block in load(/etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:220)
  at RUBY.with_job_retry(/etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:54)
  at RUBY.load(/etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:160)
  at RUBY.block in load_in_parallel(/etc/embulk/bundle_dir/jruby/2.3.0/gems/embulk-output-bigquery-0.4.5/lib/embulk/output/bigquery/bigquery_client.rb:148)

Error: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Error) failed during waiting a Load job, get_job(boxil-186303, embulk_load_job_846c15d8781cfd34d71c1efa694dff0c), errors:[{:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3452; errors: 1."}, {:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"file-00000000", :message=>"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 9, but line starting at position:40711531 contains only 9 columns."}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you checked the line that failed? It might be a CSV format issue.

Comment: What is the CSV format issue in this case? My problem is for example, records 2/1-2/28 was okay, but records 3/1-3/31 was failed. Is this a csv format issue?

Comment: I am reading that `starting at position:40711531 contains only 9 columns` try seeing what's wrong with that file/line

Comment: Okay, I will. Thank you.